# How to rotate an isometric map in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, isometric

I plan to develop a Unity game that one can call isometric, except that the player must have the ability to rotate the screen by 90 degrees. The key feature is that the rotation itself must be happening very smoothly.

Imagine an isometric map displayed on the screen. Player does the right swipe and the map smoothly performs 90 clockwise rotation. If the player swipes slowly, he actually can see how the map rotates and enjoy the details of the gameobjects graphics. But a swipe is rotating stuff only by 90 degree step.

My key question is - can such an effect be achieved in 2D isometric project, or I must go via 3D project route? I have a gut feeling that the smooth rotation cannot be achieved with 2D graphics. But on the other hand, apart from the rotating piece, I do not need 3D capabilities at all..

So, do I go for 2D project or 3D project in Unity?

Answer (score 3):

You can definitely rotate 2D isometric maps. As a great example have a look at Stronghold.

[image: Stronghold]

Let's have a look at how do achieve this rotation.

> Isometric projection is a method for visually representing
>   three-dimensional objects in two dimensions in technical and
>   engineering drawings.

Tiles are stored in a simple 2D array:

```
[[0,1,2],
[[3,4,5],
[[6,7,8]]
```

Most of the rotational magic happens with the camera. So instead of modifying the original tilemap, you only have to process it and return a new tilemap.

You can rotate the whole map by going through each tile, flipping the components and negating one of the values.

Rotate left:

```
(x, y) => (-y, x)

[[2,5,8],
[[1,4,7],
[[0,3,6]]
```

Rotate right:

```
(x, y) => (y, -x)

[[6,3,0],
[[7,4,1],
[[8,5,2]]
```

Visually the sprites stay the same. And this works fine for instant 90 degree rotations.

Adding a transition is possible, but it won't be pretty, as you will see gaps between the tiles.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. From what I understood, however, the smoothness of the transition cannot be achieved like this, right? I guess, that if I am looking for the smooth transition, I should really make a 3D project...

Comment: Yeah, I would go with 3D :)